# NHibernate map by code with OneToMany association: Select is inefficient and Inserts fail (NHibernate.StaleStateException)

Tags: nhibernate

I have a parent class and a child class. One Child is always related to just one parent, but a parent can have multiple children:

```
public class Parent
{
    public virtual string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Child> Children { get; set; } = new List<Child>();
}

public class Child
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using the latest version of NHibernate 5.1.3 and mapping by code:

```
internal class ParentMapping : ClassMapping<Parent>
{
    public ParentMapping()
    {
        Table("Parent");

        Id(x => x.Id);
        Property(x => x.Name);

        Bag(
            x => x.Children,
            map =>
            {
                map.Key(km => km.Column("ParentId"));
                map.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
                map.Cascade(Cascade.Persist);
                map.Inverse(true);
            },
            x => x.OneToMany());
    }
}

internal class ChildMapping : ClassMapping<Child>
{
    public ChildMapping()
    {
        Table("Child");

        Id(x => x.Id, x => x.Generator(Generators.Identity));
        Property(x => x.ParentId);
        Property(x => x.Name);
    }
}
```

Queries work but are quite inefficient. Instead of creating a single JOIN statement to query the children together with their parent, an explicit SELECT is made to retrieve the Child objects.

Even worse, inserts result in the following error:

```
NHibernate.StaleStateException: 'Batch update returned unexpected row count from update; actual row count: 0; expected: 3'
```

Here's a sample of a query:

```
using (var session = _sessionProvider.GetSession())
    return session.Query<T>().ToList();
```

And that's the code to save a new item:

```
using (var session = _sessionProvider.GetSession())
{
    session.Transaction.Begin();
    session.Save(newEntity);
    session.Transaction.Commit();
}
```

So everything's pretty easy.

I assume, the Bag() configuration in ParentMapping needs to be fixed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide some code to show how you query and save, may be you are using the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

Change the fetch strategy of the bag mapping to join will generate a join query, like this:

```
Bag(
    e => e.Children,
    map => {
        map.Key(km => km.Column("ParentId"));
        // map.Lazy(CollectionLazy.NoLazy);
        // change fetch str
        map.Fetch(CollectionFetchMode.Join);
        map.Cascade(Cascade.Persist);
        map.Inverse(true);
    },
    x => x.OneToMany()
);
```

And you have the collection persist as inverse (`map.Inverse(true);`), you should have a many to one mapping for `Parent` in your `Child` class like this:

```
public class Child {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    // public virtual string ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then map the `Parent` property as `ManyToOne` like this:

```
public ChildMapping() {
    // other mapping goes here
    ManyToOne(
        x => x.Parent,
        map => {
            map.Column("ParentId");
            map.Class(typeof(Parent));
            map.Fetch(FetchKind.Join);
        }
    );
}
```

But nhibernate do not include children of parent by default (maybe it is too heavy), and if you want to query children with parent instance, you can query like this:

```
using (var session = OpenSession()) {
    var query = session.Query<Parent>().Select(p => new {
        Parent = p, Children = p.Children
    });
    var data = query.ToList();
}
```

For saving entities to database, should do like this:

```
try {
    // save parent first
    var parent = new Parent();
    parent.Name = "Parent object";
    session.Save(parent);
    // then save child
    var child = new Child();
    child.Name = "Child object";
    child.Parent = parent;
    session.Save(child);
    session.Flush();
    tx.Commit();

}
catch (Exception) {
    tx.Rollback();
    throw;
}
```

Comment: The changes seem to have no effect. Still the queries select the children separately instead of using a join. Also the `StaleStateException` still shows up during insert.

Comment: Can you provide some code about how you make query and save it to the database?